# Melhor sintaxe para nome de funções em PHP

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação

Saudações, gostaria de saber qual a sintaxe correta para escrita de funções em `php`.

por exemplo:

```
public function load_default_controller() {

}
```

ou

```
public function loadDefaultController() {

}
```

A pergunta pode ser meio que sem sentido, mas por questão de, digamos "Higienização" do código, gostaria de saber qual é mais limpo, exemplo 1 ou exemplo 2?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta e adicione sobre as recomendações do PSR.

Comment: O mais limpo é ser tudo consistente, seja uma forma ou outra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não existe sintaxe correta, isso vai do gosto de cada um, o que vou lhe citar são as diferenças

- **camelCase**

  No camelCase pode haver variações do uso de letras maiúsculas e minusculas, mas na pratica geralmente usamos algo como `FooBaz` (conhecido como `camelCaps`) para nomes de classes e namespaces e usamos `fooBar` para métodos (funções nas classes conhecido como `StudyCaps`), se olhar as classes nativas do PHP e frameworks populares vai notar que a maioria usam este estilo, exemplo:

  ```
  <?php
  class FooBar
  {
      public function helloWorld()
      {
           echo 'Hello!';
      }
  }
  ```
- **snake_case**

  No snake case geralmente escrevemos tudo em minusculo e usamos o underline/underscore para dividir as palavras `lower_case_with_underscores`, isso é bastante comum em códigos PHP procedurais e funções nativas, no Python também é um pouco comum o seu uso, não é tão comum usar em classes, exemplo:

  ```
  <?php
  class foo_bar
  {
      public function hello_world()
      {
           echo 'Hello!';
      }
  }
  ```
- **Pascal Case**

  > Não sei se é a mesma coisa, mas acho que pode ser o mesmo que `StudlyCaps`

  As vezes chamado de *UpperCamelCase* ou *Dromedary Case* é bem semelhante ao *camelCase*, mas a diferença é que escrevemos a letra inicial sempre em maiúsculo, tanto para nomes de classe, quanto para métodos (acredito ser o mais comum no C#), exemplo:

  ```
  <?php
  class FooBar
  {
      public function HelloWord()
      {
           echo 'Hello!';
      }
  }
  ```

Mas o que importa mesmo é nunca misturar os dois estilos, não vai fazer mal algum, mas com certeza iria lhe confundir muito, escolha um estilo e uso apenas ele.

### PSR

Hoje muitas web-aplicações como Laravel e cakephp usam o autoload do composer, que é baseado no PSR (http://www.php-fig.org), o PSR é uma série de **recomendações** (não é obrigatoriedade), essas aplicações seguem geralmente algumas normas descritas aqui http://www.php-fig.org/psr/ em especial o [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) e [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/):

- Arquivos de usar apenas `<?php echo` e `<?=` (ou seja não use coisas como `<? echo`)
- Arquivos devem ser *UTF-8 sem BOM*
- Namespaces e classes MUST devem sempre usar "autoloading" PSR: [[PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), [PSR-4]](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).
- Nomes das classe devem sempre ser declaradas com `StudlyCaps`.
- Constantes em classes devem ser estar em CAIXA_ALTA usando underscore como separador, por exemplo `const FOO_BAR = 1;`
- Nomes das classe devem sempre ser declarados com `camelCaps`.

### spl_autload e sistemas baseados em Unix-like

Apesar das funções, classes e namespaces serem case-insensitive ao usar `spl_autload` ou composer-autoload os arquivos podem conflitar com os nomes dos namespaces e classes se os arquivos não seguirem o mesmo estilo. Por exemplo se a classe for chamada assim:

```
<?php

use Foo\Bar\Baz;

include 'autoload.php';

new Baz;
```

O arquivo deve estar com este caminho `src/Foo/Bar/Baz.php`, se fizer assim `src/Foo/Bar/baz.php` não vai encontrar o arquivo em sistemas (servidores) Linux, Mac e BSD.

Comment: Bom, PSR pra mim é mesma coisa que "Grego", rsrs mas entendi em partes, vou estudar sobre PSR, de resto ficou bem explicado, Obrigado Guilherme Nascimento.

Answer (score 2):

Como foi dito anteriormente pelo Guilherme: não existe um correto. Existe sim uma recomendação, que é bem demonstrada no [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) - um estilo de codificação.

Eu concordo com a parte que o Guilherme explica sobre "se você começa com um padrão, continue com ele até o fim". Mas é importante destacar aqui que existem padrões que são empregados pela maioria das bibliotecas PHP.

Se tivermos que tocar nesse assunto de desenvolvimento de biblioteca, recomendo amplamente que use os padrões da PSR-2.

É fácil notar que hoje em dias, a grande maioria das bibliotecas (`Zend`, `Laravel`, `Guzzle`, `Gregwar`), utilizam o padrão empregado pela `PSR-2` (ele trata de outros assuntos, e não só da nomenclatura de métodos).

Não estou dizendo que você deve fazer tudo igual essas bibliotecas fazem, mas é importante, no desenvolvimento de bibliotecas, manter um padrão, para facilitar usuários acostumados com os padrões empregados em bibliotecas a usar a sua.

Se você pensar em como as classes ou interfaces padrões do PHP são escritas, por exemplo, você pode usar o bom senso e fazer algo similar, para poder apresentar  um código mais próximo da "realidade" da linguagem.

Observe por exemplo o resumo da interface `ArrayAccess`:

```
interface ArrayAccess {
    /* Métodos */
    abstract public boolean offsetExists ( mixed $offset )
    abstract public mixed offsetGet ( mixed $offset )
    abstract public void offsetSet ( mixed $offset , mixed $value )
    abstract public void offsetUnset ( mixed $offset )
}
```

Observe que os nomes dos métodos estão em CamelCase (como explicado pelo Guilherme).

## Resumo da PSR (para o seu caso)

Como um Resumo da PSR-2 (o que eu lembro de cabeça), posso afirmar que os padrões são:

- Use camelCase para nome dos métodos de uma classe.
- As palavras `final` ou `abstract` devem vir antes da visibilidade (`public`, `protected` ou `private`) dos métodos.
- Use snake_case para as funções.
- As chaves das funções ou métodos devem conter uma quebra de linha.

Reforçando novamente que isso é uma recomendação, não é obrigatório.

Answer (score 1):

Pessoalmente, gosto de utilizar o estilo camelCase.

A escolha esta mais relacionada ao gosto pessoal ou ao padrão seguido pela equipe de desenvolvimento.

Recomendo a leitura dos seguintes posts (são curtos)
http://www.1bit.com.br/content.1bit/weblog/programando_melhor_nomenclatura
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/253/padroes-de-nomenclaturas-guia-de-consulta-rapida.aspx